# json_index.php запускаю файл ввожду данные , но действий нет почему

Tags: php

json_answer.php:

```
<?php
  // Преобразуем JSON-данные в массив
  $arr = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
  // Объединяем содержимое в строку
  $name = trim(implode(" ", $arr));

  $result = "Здравствуйте";
  if(!empty($name))
  $result .= ", $name";
  $result .= "!";

  // Отдаем результат
  echo htmlspecialchars($result);
?>
```

json_index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <title>Передача JSON-данных</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/json_index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id='js-hello'>Здравствуйте!</p>
  <form action="/json_answer.php" method="GET">
  <p>Имя: <input type="text" name="name" value="" /></p>
  <p>Фамилия: <input type="text" name="family" value="" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Представиться"><p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

json_index.js:

```
// Назначаем обработчики, только после полной загрузки  документа
$(function(){
  // Обработчик нажатия на кнопку submit
  $('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e){
  // Предотвращаем обычное поведение элемента
  e.preventDefault();
  // Формируем JSON из полей формы
  var json = {
  name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
  family:  $('input[name=family]').val()
  }
  // Отправляем асинхронный POST-запрос по адресу
  // указанному в атрибуте action формы
  $.ajax({
  url: $('form').prop('action'),
  method: 'POST',
  data: 'json=' + JSON.stringify(json)
  })
  // В случае успешного получения ответа от сервера
  .done(function(msg){
  // Заменяем надпись Здравствуйте в поле p#is-hello
  $('#js-hello').html(msg);
  });
  });
});
```

Comment: а вы не ставили точку останова вот здесь - `$('#js-hello').html(msg);` доходите вы туда или нет?

Comment: какую точку нужно?

Comment: Ваш код абсолютно рабочий. Возможно у вас какие-то проблемы с серверной частью. Откройте в браузере консоль разработчика (в Chrome это по F12) и во вкладке Сеть(Network) посмотрите какие запросы отправляются и какие не срабатывают.

Answer (score 0):

Что то много написанно, просто делаем в форме

```
<form id='test'>
<input type='text' name='json[name]' />
<input type='text' name='json[family]' />
</form>
```

В js сериализуем и шлем ajax

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e){
  // Предотвращаем обычное поведение элемента
  e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
      url: $('form').prop('action'),
      method: 'POST',
      data: $('test').serialize(),
      dataType: "json" // для контента
      }).done(function(data){
          $('#js-hello').html(data.msg);
      });
});
```

ну и последний штрих это

```
<?php
  // @todo указываем контент тайп
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  // Преобразуем JSON-данные в массив
  $arr = $_POST['json'];
  // Объединяем содержимое в строку
  $name = trim(implode(" ", $arr));

  $result = "Здравствуйте";
  if(!empty($name))
  $result .= ", $name";
  $result .= "!";

  // Отдаем результат
  echo json_encode(['msg' => htmlspecialchars($result)]);
```